# Stopwatch always outputs 00:00:00:00

Tags: c#, wpf, stopwatch

In my WPF-Programm there is a button with this code-behinde:

```
**Outside the Click event:**
bool started = false;

**In the Click Event:**
if (started == false)
{
    started = true;

    btnStart.Content = "Stop";

    //---------Clock Code-------------
    stopwatch.Start();
}
else
{
    started = false;
    btnStart.Content = "Start";

    //---------Clock Code------------

    stopwatch.Stop();
    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;

    // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", 
      ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    tbDuration.Text = elapsedTime;
}
```

But if I start the program and push the button, it allways displays 0.
I can't debug it, because Visual Studio crashes...

What do I do wrong?

Or do you have better ways to do this?
I simply want to measure time between two presses and output it into a Textbox.

I'd also would like that the time would be monitored live in the Textbox.

Thanks

Comment: If this code is in the Click() event handler for your button then the `started == false` condition will always be run because you declare and set the `started` variable immediately before - this also means the moment you leave that method the variable goes out of scope so you won't maintain any state information for next time you enter the method.

Comment: You need to use backgroundjob for the purpose to keep ui updated

Comment: @slugster Thank you for your answer, the started is mis placed here. It is outside the Click Event.

Comment: `I can't debug it, because Visual Studio crashes...`  This is your first problem, you will need to figure this out, you cant ask simple questions all the time when all you need to do is debug the application. i think instead of writing programs you need to work out why your visual studio crashes first

Comment: Also if your stopwatch isn't a instance member then you cant measure time

Comment: @TheGeneral I was able to debug the seconde part. It allready says 0 when I stop the watch. I only can't debug the first part of the if. But I don't think the error is there.

Comment: @TheGeneral Okey, I will google what how to do that. Thanks

Comment: `private StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();`

Comment: I think you have a more basic problem of `if-else` and bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code looks something like this it works fine:

```
    public Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    bool started = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (started == false)
        {
            started = true;

            button1.Text = "Stop";

            //---------Clock Code-------------

            stopwatch.Start();




        }
        else
        {
            started = false;
            button1.Text = "Start";

            //---------Clock Code------------

            stopwatch.Stop();
            // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
            TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;

            // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                ts.Milliseconds / 10);

            MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. My mistake was, that I need to make the StopWatch public and not to put it into the Click Event

Comment: Do you also have a solution how to display the time live into a Textbox?

Comment: You'd need to start a separate thread to avoid locking up the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: (From @TheGeneral)
Put the stopwatch into an instance member:

```
private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
```